# 'alt+left' for going to previous page doesn't work with testcafe but works fine manually

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, accessibility, testcafe

I'm trying to go back to the previous page from the existing page from my `TestCafe` code using:

```
await t.pressKey('alt+left');
```

But this doesn't seem to work. There is no change in the page. But manually when I verify in the browser, it seems to work fine.

Could someone help me with this, I want to be able to go back to the previous page using keyboard strokes alone.

Comment: No. I've not implemented it specifically. either 'backspace' or 'alt+left arrow' should work ideally to go back to previous page. Backspace is not supported for the webpage I'm writing code for. Using testcafe, I'm unable to go back using alt+left. do you know of any other way I can go back? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 7):

TestCafe doesn't support the `alt+left` key combination (see the list of supported key combinations [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/press-key.html)).

You can use the browser's [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to navigate between pages.

*See an example:*

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
  .page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/`;

const back = ClientFunction(() => window.history.back());

test('test', async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/getting-started/');

    await back();
});
```

Comment: I currently use this but was looking for a way to do it with just key strokes. Thank you :)